# ImportError: cannot import name csrf_exemp

Tags: python, swift, django, csrf-protection

I wanna connect my Swift app & Python Django Server in sending Image(I wanna send images from Swift app to Server)
When I tried to do it,I got an error

```
<div id="info">
  <h2>Help</h2>

    <p>Reason given for failure:</p>
    <pre>
    CSRF cookie not set.
    </pre>


  <p>In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when
  <a
  href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/">Django's
  CSRF mechanism</a> has not been used correctly.  For POST forms, you need to
  ensure:</p>

  <ul>
    <li>Your browser is accepting cookies.</li>

    <li>The view function passes a <code>request</code> to the template's <a
    href="https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/#django.template.backends.base.Template.render"><code>render</code></a>
    method.</li>

    <li>In the template, there is a <code>{% csrf_token
    %}</code> template tag inside each POST form that
    targets an internal URL.</li>

    <li>If you are not using <code>CsrfViewMiddleware</code>, then you must use
    <code>csrf_protect</code> on any views that use the <code>csrf_token</code>
    template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.</li>

    <li>The form has a valid CSRF token. After logging in in another browser
    tab or hitting the back button after a login, you may need to reload the
    page with the form, because the token is rotated after a login.</li>
  </ul>

  <p>You're seeing the help section of this page because you have <code>DEBUG =
  True</code> in your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,
  and only the initial error message will be displayed.  </p>

  <p>You can customize this page using the CSRF_FAILURE_VIEW setting.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

So,I think maybe adding csrf decorators to Django Server is good.
I added it to my codes like

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.views.decorators.http import require_POST
from .forms import RegisterForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from .models import Post
from .forms import UserImageForm
from .models import ImageAndUser
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exemp
@csrf_exempt
def upload_save(request):

    photo_id = request.POST.get("p_id", "")

    if (photo_id):
        photo_obj = Post.objects.get(id=photo_id)
    else:
        photo_obj = Post()

    files = request.FILES.getlist("files[]")


    photo_obj.image = files[0]
    # photo_obj.image2 = files[1]
    # photo_obj.image3 = files[2]

    photo_obj.save()
    # return render(request, "registration/accounts/photo.html")

    photos = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'photos': photos,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/photo.html', context)
```

But,when I run my server,error happens
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exemp
ImportError: cannot import name csrf_exemp   .
Traceback says

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x103947b90>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/KenshinServer/KenshinServer/urls.py", line 24, in <module>
    url(r'^accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/urls/__init__.py", line 50, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/KenshinServer/accounts/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "/Users/XXX/Desktop/KenshinServer/accounts/views.py", line 11, in <module>
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exemp
ImportError: cannot import name csrf_exemp
```

Why does this error happen?I think only adding `from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exemp` & @csrf_exempt is enough,but is it wrong?(Should I add  something else?)
How can I fix this?

Comment: You have a typo, you are missing a 't' in the import line - csrf_exempt

Comment: it's `django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt` you made a typo

Answer (score 1):

There is typo error in your code it is `csrf_exempt` not `csrf_exemp`

Answer (score 0):

change

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exemp
```

to

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```